# "QtQuick version 2.0 is not installed" while trying to run CurrencyConverter Example for Ubuntu Phone

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt

I was following the [step-by-step](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/mobile/currency-converter-phone-app/) guide on how to develop an Ubuntu Phone application but Qt Creator throughs the error message (module "QtQuick" version 2.0 is not installed) when I run it with QMLscene. Seems to me that Qt Creator utilizes Qt4 instead of Qt5. How can I fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem when running from Plasma (with a Plasmoid). Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 5):

You are using qmlviewer when you should be using qmlscene. Quote from the tutorial:

To start QML applications, either during the prototyping or final stages, you will use QML Scene. QML Scene is a command-line application that interprets and runs QML code.

...

Here's a tip: although Qt Creator does not yet support qmlscene as QML viewer, you can invoke it from within the IDE. Here’s how:

1. In Qt Creator, go to Tools > Options…
2. Choose the External Tools tab, then in the pane select the Preview (qmlviewer) entry
3. On the Executable: field on the right, replace the contents with /opt/qt5/bin/qmlscene.
4. Optionally change the command name by double-clicking on the Preview (qmlviewer) entry from above. You can call it Preview (qmlscene).
5. Click on OK to save the changes.

You can also run QML Scene from the command line:

```
$ qmlscene /path/to/application.qml
```

Comment: Seems that some stuff is missing on my 12.10. Directory /opt/qt5/bin/ does not exist. The only folder is /opt/qt5/imports/. How can I install the whole qt5 pack?

Comment: Are you sure you've followed the instructions on the Ubuntu website fully? Running `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-beta1 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qt5-meta-full && echo 'export PATH=/opt/qt5/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc` should create the directory /opt/qt5/bin.

Answer (score 1):

Hi~ I had the same problem like yours that Qt Creator throughs the error message

(module "QtQuick" version 2.0 is not installed).

And I was also following the [step-by-step](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/mobile/currency-converter-phone-app/) guide just like you. 
Finally I have fixed it now. [image: http://ubuntuone.com/1qJHsJxyWq0RH3yvEvQ6ME] this image shows that you have something wrong in configuration the **qmlscene**. I also had configured the **qmlscene**, but it had the same error like you had done.

Finally I found that when I configured the path of **qmlscene** , I had typed a backspace before the **"/opt/qt5/bin/qmlscene"** . So it didn't work. I just want to tell you what I've done to cause this error.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to change the default **qmlviewer**:

1. In Qt Creator go to: `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Environment`
2. Choose the `External Tools` tab, then in the panel select the `Preview` (qmlviewer) entry
3. On the Executable: field on the right, replace the contents with `/opt/qt5/bin/qmlscene` or `/usr/bin/qmlscene` (in Ubuntu 12.10).